# JSF2.0 h:commandlink action attribute not binding to a method

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss-weld

I have an application running JSF2.0 on the front end.  In the backend instead of using managed beans I'm using weld's named beans.  The bean in question is annotated @Named @Singleton @Startup and is an EJB Singleton. The bean gets the top level category to populate the front end.  In the top level navigation of the front end I have code that look like so

```
<h:dataTable var="items" value="#{topCategorySingleton.topCat}">
<h:column>
<h:commandLink class="menu-link" action="#{categoryBackingBean.category}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{categoryBackingBean.catID}" value="#{item.sku}" />
 <h:outputText value="#{item.title}" />
 </h:commandLink>
 </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

When this code runs I get an error stating
javax.servlet.ServletException: The class 'com.webintel.backingbeans.org$jboss$weld$bean-testing-SessionBean-CategoryBackingBean_$$_WeldProxy' does not have the property 'category'.

I thought the action attribute of commandLink should bind to a method of the bean, not a property?  Anyone have any ideas?

At startup the @Singleton is started and the code as follows:

```
@Singleton
@Named
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(CONTAINER)
public class TopCategorySingleton{
  public TopCategoryStingleton(){}
  private int sku;
  private String title;
  private List<TopCategorySingleton> topCat;
....getters and setters
  public void getTop_Cat(){
   ....logic
   setTopCat(List<TopCateogrySingleton>);
  }
```

Then the backing bean code look like so:

```
@Stateless
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CategoryBackingBean{
  public CategoryBackingBean(){}
  private int catID;
  ....getters and setters
  public String category(){
    ...logic
    if(!true){
      return "error";
    }
    return "success";
  }
```

For some reason it is still not binding the categoryBackingBean.category to the method.  I am running this app on a Glassfish 3.1 server with Java 6.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you try use brackets 'category()' or do you have category method in your bean. because seems like application looking for getCategory(); field in your bean.

Comment: I've tried using 'category()' in the action attribute, still didn't work.  I didn't think it would, the action attribute should bind to an action method on the bean, and yes I have a category method in the bean.

Comment: have you referenced the category method somewhere else in your xhtml?, Check even in the commented code!

Comment: For testing purposes, I eliminated the dataTable and hard coded the list of top categories with the commandLink's for each and it worked perfectly.  I don't want to hard code these values as they might change, so I would like to generate the list dynamically.

Comment: Where's the backing bean code? Can we see the method implementation/signature?

Comment: I've updated my original post with the code you asked for.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ojota Find the problem, there was commented at the bottom of the page.  I didn't think that would be a problem, guess I was wrong...not the first of last.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, that is a common error. If you want to avoid the problem, you can use put this into your web.xml so that the comments are really ignored <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>